# Symfony2 Collection Form does not fill join column

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have 2 entities, Product and Product_Types.

This is the relationship between them:

```
manyToOne:
    product:
      targetEntity: Product
      joinColumn:
        name: product_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

When I add a new Product, I want to be able to add types to this product with the same form.

```
            ->add('productColor', 'collection', array("type" => new ProductColorType(), "allow_add" => true, 'prototype' => true))
```

This is how I embed the form(s).

The 'data_class' is set for both ProductType and ProductTypesType, and when I add a new product with types, everything is fine, except for one thing, symfony/doctrine does not set the 'product_id' column, so there will be no relationship between my Product and its types.

Comment: It's funny, I'd been looking for a solution for ages before I asked this question, and then I found a solution, I just set the product for the types before I persist the Product. It solves the problem, but still, I don't think that it should be done this way.

Answer (score 5):

You need to cross link your entities manually. Neither Symfony nor Doctrine do this for you. You can do this for example within an add...() method:

```
public function getProductColors()
{
    return $this->productColors;
}

public function addProductColor(ProductColor $color)
{
    $this->productColors->add($color);
    $color->setProduct($this);
}
```

Then three requirements have to be fulfilled in order for this to work:

- you are running Symfony master
- you are running Doctrine 2.1.7/2.2.3
- you set the "by_reference" option of the "collection" field to `false`

If you do all this, you should be fine.

Comment: Calling setProduct() in addProductColor() would work. However, according to the documentation, setting by_reference to false should invoke setProductColors(), which doesn't seem to be the case. Any idea?

Comment: Depends on whether the add/remove methods are available. If they are, they are used instead of the setter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to also persist the productColors before your entity manager flush.